# std::list static_cast derived iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, stdlist

I have a list defined as:

```
std::list<CExcited*> mExcitedList;
```

Excited is defined as:

```
class CExcited
{
public: 
    CExcited::CExcited(){}
    virtual int getAnswer() = 0;
};
```

I have a derived class:

```
class CExcitedA :: public CExcited
{
public:
    CExcitedA::CExcitedA(){}
    int getAnswer() {return 1;}
};
```

And another:

```
class CExcitedB :: public CExcited
{
public:
    CExcitedB::CExcitedB(){}
    int getAnswer() {return 2;}
};
```

I add some elements to the list

```
CExcitedA* excitedA = new ExcitedA();
mExcitedList.add_back(excitedA);

CExcitedB* excitedB = new ExcitedB();
mExcitedList.add_back(excitedB);
```

and when I iterate the list I can't work out how to find out at runtime which class is it I have added.

I have tried to no avail

```
for (std::list<Excited*>::iterator iter = mExcitedList.begin(); iter != mExcitedList.end(); iter++)
{
    if (typeid(*iter) == typeid(CExcitedA*))
    {
    }
    if (typeid(dynamic_cast<CExcitedA*>(*iter)) == typeid(CExcitedA*))
    {
    }
}
```

This seems like it should be straight forward, but I am not able to get it.

Edited From here with the answer

```
    CExcitedA* testA = dynamic_cast<CExcitedA*> (*iter);
    if (testA != 0)
    { 
        std::cout << "ES: " << dynamic_cast<CExcitedA*> (*iter)->getAnswer() << std::endl;
    }

    CExcitedB* testB = dynamic_cast<CExcitedB*> (*iter);
    if (testB != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "EB: " << dynamic_cast<CExcitedB*> (*iter)->getAnswer() << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the information of what class it is?

Comment: Each class implements specific member functions and based on its class I will be able to know which method to call.

Comment: You cannot implement this with virtual functions?

Answer (score 1):

you already have a means to distinguish class type why not use it?

```
for (std::list<Excited*>::iterator iter = mExcitedList.begin(); iter != mExcitedList.end(); iter++){
{
   int classType = iter->getAnswer();
   switch (classType) {
    case 1: cout << "class A";
            break;
    case 2: cout << "class B";
            break;
    default: cout << "unknown class";
   }
}
```

There is also run time type id check:
typeid(*iter).name() that would give you "class name"